# Why is this not the same as 2d convolution?

Tags: convolution, neural-networks

I am currently studying this [paper](https://yorkspace.library.yorku.ca/xmlui/handle/10315/29980) (page 53), in which the suggest convolution to be done in a special manner.

This is the formula:

\begin{equation} \label{eq:equation}
q_{j,m} = \sigma \left(\sum_i \sum_{n=1}^{F} o_{i,n+m-1} \cdot  w_{i,j,n} + w_{0,j} \right)
\end{equation}

Here is their explanation:

As shown in Fig. 4.2, all input feature maps (assume I in total), $O_i (i = 1, · · · , I)$ are mapped into a number of feature maps (assume $J$ in total), $Q_j (j = 1, · · · , J)$ in the convolution layers based on a number of local filters ($I × J$ in total), $w_{ij}$ $(i = 1, · · · , I; j = 1, · · · , J)$. The mapping can be represented as the well-known convolution operation in signal processing.
Assuming input feature maps are all one dimensional, each unit of one feature map in the convolution layer can be computed as equation \ref{eq:equation} (equation above).

where $o_{i,m}$ is the $m$-th unit of the $i$-th input feature map $O_i$, $q_{j,m}$ is the $m$-
th unit of the $j$-th feature map $Q_j$ of the convolution layer, $w_{i,j,n}$ is the $n$th element of the weight vector, $w_{i,j}$, connecting the $i$th feature map of the input to the $j$th feature map of the convolution layer, and $F$ is called the filter size which is the number of input bands that each unit of the convolution layer receives.

So far so good:

What i basically understood from this is what I've tried to illustrate in this image.

[image]

It seem to me what they are doing is actually processing all data points up to F, and across all feature maps.  Basically moving in both x-y direction, and compute on point from that.

Isn't that basically 2d- convolution on a 2d image of size $(I x F)$ with a filter equal to the image size?. 
The weight doesn't seem to differ at all have any importance here..?

Comment: First of all if it was a convolution one of them would be backwards, e.g. - sign on one of the variables and + on the other. If anything this could maybe be a correlation ( both are in same direction ).

Comment: @mathreadler I am not sure I understand problem.. where is the sign confusion?

Comment: But there are several other unclear things, three indexes on one of the factors and only two on the other, for example.

Comment: indexes n+m-1 and n, if it was a convolution then either -n+m-1 or n-m-1 instead.

Comment: $w_{i,j}$ refers to the full weight matrix, and $w_{i,j,n}$ refers to $n$-th element of the $w_{i,j}$ weight matrix.  @mathreadler

Comment: regarding "n+m-1" I think it's because they don't start from zero but start from 1..  1+1-1 = 0 ? @mathreadler

Comment: its not a convolution if one index does not count down and the other up. $-1$ would only be a shift of the filter (or the signal) anyway.

Comment: So the way i've drawn it,  is incorrect?.. 
or?...

Comment: its not a convolution if one index does not count down and the other up. $-1$ would only be a shift of the filter (or the signal) anyway.

Comment: just read about convolution. wikipedia is usually okay and probably mathworld too

Comment: @mathreadler I am still not sure what you are hinting at..  So i doesn't move in both direction,  but only moves in one direction, but would it not due to its filter size (equal to image portion) and "movement" (only in one direction)  be considered a 1d convolution.

Comment: Just read up on the definition of convolution and you will see that it is first argument summing in one direction and the other opposite direction.

Comment: Thats it.. I've been reading it up on it.. Lately from here https://cs.nju.edu.cn/wujx/paper/CNN.pdf


What I am trying to illustrate in the image, is that all the feature in input feature map 1 is being multiplied with their weight and summed together. 
The same is done  for all the feature maps, and end with all the summed input features map, being summed together to one value.

It moves in both directions?.. so isn't convolution? Sorry for dragging this out, or sounding like an idiot..

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer the definition of [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is wrong. The real definition is in the continous case:
$$(f*g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$$
and in the discrete case:

$$(f*g)[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f[k]g[n-k]$$

You can clearly see that $\tau$ and $k$ both have opposite sign in the function arguments, which correspond to indexes in your notation.

Comment: But... is this the same as being performed in neural networks or convolutional neural  network.. I don't think you can relate it like this.. look here http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-Understanding-Convolutions/ 

Or this snapshot http://imgur.com/a/RgcIV

Comment: Maybe the rest of what they are doing is correct, but saying that is a convolution is wrong as it is a correllation.